# Is it possible to delete a file in VBA Word 2013 and send it to the Recycle Bin?

Tags: vba, recycle-bin

I delete a file using

```
Sub RenameActiveFile()    by  Kmote

 '''' 

 ' Delete old file:
 With New FileSystemObject   ' (this line requires: Tools->References->Microsoft scripting runtime)
    If .FileExists(strFileFullName) Then
        .DeleteFile strFileFullName
    End If
End With
```

The file is deleted but not sent to the RecycleBin,
can anyone tell me if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

VB can do this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdx72k4b.aspx

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\test.txt",
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,.
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
```

Or this way:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(   "C:\test.txt",  
 FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,  
 FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,  
 FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
```

A third option is to move the file to the Recycle Bin, and if there are no errors, then delete the original. This might work better for older version of office as the delete to recycle bin functions are relatively recent additions.